# Recursive component usage in Angular / Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, angular10

Backstory:

I'm building a group-able data table in an Angular 10 app, in which I would like to DRY as much as possible.

The idea is that the user can **"group-by"** any number of columns in the list

**"group by eye color"** then **"group by hair color"**

```
eye-color: green:
  |___hair-color: brown:
    |___User 1
    |___User 2
    |___hair-color: blonde:
      |___User 3
      |___User 4
eye-color: brown:
  |___hair-color: brown:
    |___User 5
    |___User 6
  |___hair-color: blonde:
    |___User 7
    |___User 8
```

The data's not important, just for context.

There's a lot of files involved so I'll summarize with pseudo code:

My top level component would look like so:

```html
<!-- Show either the plain list or the groups, depending on group-by  -->
<div *ngIf="groupBy">
  <item-table ... ></item-table>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!groupBy">
  <item-group-list ... ></item-group-list>
</div>
```

Then, within the  component, iterating through each grouping leads to another **single-group** component

```html
<div *ngFor="let group of groupList">
  <span>{{ group.count }} {{ group.label }}</span>

  <single-group ... ></single-group>

</div>
```

Finally, within the **single-group** component, there are two conditions:

1. The group is the end of the tree, in which I just show the list for that group.
2. The group has sub-groups, in which I want to recurse and show the **group-list**, now embedded and filtered down.

```html
<div *ngIf="!hasSubGroups()">
  <item-table ... ></item-table>
</div>

<div *ngIf="hasSubGroups()">
  <item-group-list ... ></item-group-list>
</div>
```

The issue, is that this is causing a circular dependency back to **item-group-list**.

e.g:

```
<top-level-component>
  |__<item-table>
OR|
  |__<item-group-list>         <------
       |                              |
       |__<single-group>              |
            |__<item-table>           |
          OR|                         |
            |__<item-group-list>   ---
```

Sometimes the page loads and works beautifully, as intended. Other times however, I get an error:

`Cannot access 'ItemGroupListComponent' before initialization at Module.ItemGroupListComponent`

This error seems to happen at random, leading me to believe it's something with the load order, caused by this circular reference. A few other posts also seem to point to that.

If I create a separate, duplicate "item-group-list" component that's only used as a sub-list, it works fine but I'd like to avoid that if I can.

Any ideas?

Comment: i don't know about Ur code but i want to send you an image. i want to view it as more of a algoirthm question.can you not optimize your algorithm like this? https://ibb.co/3vYDjKD

Comment: Could you filter the duplicate components out of the subgroup when a user selects a grouping or with a pipe? it wouldn't make sense to  have `brown hair > green eyes > brown hair`

Comment: This pattern is not an issue. I've implemented it myself in a project. The question is - what data are you providing for your components?

It sounds like you have a circular reference because of the data you pass in to the children.

Maybe you can try setting up an easier example on stackblitz and share with us?

Comment: That absolutely works I've done much the same. When the error occurs, does it happen before the application bootstraps?